# Algorithm / working approach to get a random list of data

Tags: android, performance, algorithm

I am working on a android schedule app but that isn't matter , the problem is a algorithm / methodology so you are welcome to just write the pusedo code to answer.

The data is like this

```
Place 
=============
Name
lat 
lng
duration
isBookMark
type

Note: There are **only** two type: Shop , Park ,
duration is the time base on hour e.g. 1 => 1hour, 0.5 hour etc.... 
lat lng are the location unit
```

So, I would like to generate a random place list based on the following criteria:

```
1.) There are 2 duration limit

if short limit, then I need to get exactly 1 Park and some Shop  , based on the hour 3 - 5 is given
if medium limit, I need to get exactly 2 Park and some Shop, based on the hour 6 -8 is given
if long limit, then I need to get exactly 3 Park and some Shop  , based on the hour 9 - 11 is given

2. ) The user can select whether the bookmarked item is higher priority, so it may need to handle bookmark higher priority when select the item. 

3. ) Also, the next place chosen must be the nearest place. You can assume there is already a `calcuateDistanceDiff()` function aviliable
```

So , how to generate a list in the above case:

I have tried to simply like "hardcode" to handle the duration limit one by one e.g. 
get one Park first and get the next by checking the priority / distance one by one , but there should be some more wise way to create a more generic "methodology" to handle this, in terms of better performance and elegant.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add for each Park few Nearest Shops on init??

But you'll have to change few things to implements class inhéritance :

```
class Place {
    string name;
    LatLng latLng
    double dur;
    bool isBookMark;
}
class Park extends Place {
    ArrayList<Shop> nearestParks;
}
class Shop extends Place {
}
```

When your are creating a Shop, you look at all the Parks and add in the list if near enought.